# Slow copy paste in Excel vba

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, performance, copy-paste

I have the below code and find that copy-pasting is slow and the interior colour is slow as well.

I am trying to deal with this code with 700,000 rows + 120 columns of data.

Any suggestion to improve the speed.

Currently, it can take me more than 20 mins to finish this row of code.

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.DisplayStatusBar = False

For i = keycolumns + 2 To ILcol + 1
    
    'Result.Cells(1, resultcolumn).EntireColumn.Insert
    rColumnLetter = Split(Cells(1, resultcolumn - 1).Address, "$")(1)
    iColumnLetter = Split(Cells(1, i - 1).Address, "$")(1)
    IL.Range(iColumnLetter & "1:" & iColumnLetter & ILrow).Copy Result.Range(rColumnLetter & "1:" & rColumnLetter & ILrow)
    colNum = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Result.Cells(1, resultcolumn - 1).Value, PL.Range("1:1"), 0)
    
    Result.Cells(1, resultcolumn) = Result.Cells(1, resultcolumn - 1) & " Postload - " & colNum
    
    'Result.Cells(1, resultcolumn + 1).EntireColumn.Insert
    Result.Cells(1, resultcolumn + 1) = Result.Cells(1, resultcolumn - 1) & " Comparison"
    ColumnLetter = Split(Cells(1, resultcolumn + 1).Address, "$")(1)
    Result.Range(ColumnLetter & "1:" & ColumnLetter & ILrow).Interior.Color = RGB(146, 208, 80)
    
    resultcolumn = resultcolumn + (2 * (i - i + 1)) + 1
    
    
Next i
```

Comment: Could you include a description what the code is supposed to do?

Comment: @VBasic2008 , my code suppose to copy the data to another sheet and insert 2 blank columns for each column

Comment: You mean copy `A` to `A`, `B` to `D`, `C` to `G`...etc.?

Comment: @VBasic2008 yes i did that but its very slow and took long time as my data have 710k row and 110 columns of data

Comment: Have you tried instead of using copy/paste of ranges, do a direct transfer from cell to cell using `For`. One for the columns and the other for the rows? Is that possible with your data? Take a look at this website https://www.xylos.com/en/learning/blog/tip-1-save-time-processing-data-excel-vba-copy-cells

Comment: @Gassz thanks for the wedsite for reading i will try and update the outcome later

Comment: @Gassz i have tried for loop it take  longer time than copy paste

Comment: ow okay. it's a hard one. good luck!

Answer (score -1):

In my experience it is better to avoid operations directly on the sheets. What I would do is:

1. create an array variable
2. resize the array so it can hold all the data
3. populate the array with the actions currently included in your 'for' loop
4. print the array into the sheet

The final result would be close to this:

```
public sub populateArray()
    dim arr_data() as Variant
    dim numberOfRows,numberOfColumns,currentRow,currentCollumn   as integer
    currentRow = 0
    currentCollumn = 0
    numberOfRows = 10
    numberOfColumns = 10
    redim arr_data(numberOfRows,numberOfColumns) 
    
    for currentRow to numberOfRows
        for currentCollumn to numberOfColumns
            arr_data (currentRow,currentCollumn) = "TEXT"
        next currentCollumn
    next currentRow
    
    with activesheet
        .range("A1") = arr_data
    next with
    
end sub
```

Please note that I did not test the above code, feel free to adjust it to your needs.

Comment: i am not so familiar with array, can I have example to insert columns in array?

Comment: It is out of memory  for my number of row = 798000 and number of columns = 318

Comment: change type declaration from 'as integer' to a 'as Long' - long type can hold numbers from -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647.